# Where do I start with programming for cardboard vr?

Tags: android, google-cardboard

I want to start making a project on Google Cardboard. I know android programming, not expert level but doable. I really don't know where to start, please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't had a chance to try it myself yet but there's a ["getting started" demo walk-through for Android](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/unity/get-started) you could try if you haven't already? It uses Unity, the Cardboard SDK and the Android SDK.

From the google developer link above:

> This page describes how to build and deploy the demo Cardboard scene
>   included in the Cardboard SDK for Unity, presuming little prior Unity
>   experience.
>
> If you are looking for instructions for building Cardboard on iOS with
>   Unity, see the Getting Started with Unity for iOS page.
>
> The demo recreates the Cardboard SDK for Android Treasure Hunt demo
>   app within Unity to illustrate:
>
> Using the CardboardMain prefab to set up a stereo camera rig that
>   tracks the user's head orientation. Handling trigger input events, such 
>   as magnet click.
>
> Setting up Cardboard
>
> Download the latest version of Unity.
>
> Download the Cardboard SDK for Unity.
>
> Download the Cardboard Demo for Unity.
>
> Download the Android SDK if you don't already have it. The "SDK Tools Only" option is sufficient. Follow the installation instructions up to and including “Get the latest SDK tools”.
>
> Open Unity, creating a new project.